# Add a list of values to an existing list of dictionaries (performance-critical)

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to add a list of value like this one:

```
l = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

to an existing list of dictionaries like this:

```
d = [{'id': 1, 'type': 'normal'},
     {'id': 2, 'type': 'low'},
     {'id': 3, 'type': 'hight'}]
```

so that the end results will be like this:

```
d = [{'id': 1, 'type': 'normal', 'groups': [1, 2]},
     {'id': 2, 'type': 'low', 'groups': [2, 3]},
     {'id': 3, 'type': 'hight', 'groups': [3, 4]}]
```

Both list are of same size, and the index in both lists must match.

Performance is critical.

Thanks

Comment: are both data structure guaranteed to be the same length?

Comment: @aws_apprentice Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be quite a bit faster going with an approach that doesn't create any new lists or dictionaries or use indexing. This is the fastest I've found (and, in my opinion, the simplest):

```py
for sub_d, groups in zip(d, l):
    sub_d['groups'] = groups
```

In my tests this is about three as fast as `d = [{**s, 'groups': g} for s, g in zip(d, l)]` - 0.085s for a list of 1000000 dictionaries vs 0.25s - and about twice as fast as the `for i in range(len(d))` approach. It also has the advantage over the former - although in some cases it *might* be a disadvantage - that since it updates the dictionaries in place you can update a long list of them without creating a new list.

Two things I think are worth noting, though: one, the performance of different approaches in general often varies significantly depending on the exact structure of your data and the rest of your code; and two, the performance of any given bit of code is often much less critical than you might think. Is a difference of microseconds really critical in your code? Or are you dealing with millions of dictionaries and seconds matter? Personally, I think it's generally too soon to talk a lot about optimization before your code is more or less complete *and* you've determined it's too slow *and* you've profiled it in realistic circumstances.

Comment: Please don't write "above" when referring to other answers, as the ordering is dynamic and this can be confusing. This is what the answer share links are for.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
for i in range(len(d)):
  d[i]["groups"] = l[i]
```

Gives me:

```
[{'id': 1, 'type': 'normal', 'groups': [1, 2]}, {'id': 2, 'type': 'low', 'groups': [2, 3]}, {'id': 3, 'type': 'hight', 'groups': [3, 4]}]
```

In time:

`1.9000000000005124e-05 seconds`

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip` the list of dicts and the list of lists in a list comprehension that outputs dicts with the sub-dicts unpacked and the sub-lists added to the `groups` key:

```
d = [{**s, 'groups': g} for s, g in zip(d, l)]
```

Comment: This is fast! I never thought of that. Thanks. Time - `9.974000022339169e-06`