# How do I add a new key value pair to a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hi new python coder here, let's say I have a list of dictionaries:

```
data = [{'stat_1': 'name_1', 'stat_2': 10}, {'stat_1': 'name_2', 'stat_2': 12}]
```

Now I want to add to this list of dictionaries a stat_3 that has the corresponding values for each dictionary item of 100 and 120.

My intended result is:

```
updated_data = [{'stat_1': 'name_1', 'stat_2': 10, 'stat_3': 100}, {'stat_1': 'name_2', 'stat_2': 12, 'stat_3: 120}]
```

I know you can append to one dictionary item but how would I go about this with two dictionary items in a list? Is a for loop required? Appreciate the help!

Comment: Just use an inline for loop and add to each

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please review [help/how-to-ask]. Your question seems to be asked many times; for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/55465957/5660315.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
data[0]['stat_3'] = 100
data[1]['stat_3'] = 120
```

if you have a lot of dictionaries in your `data` list i would do this:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
   data[i]['stat_3'] = value #(whatever value you want)
```

Comment: Got so close! Except 100, 120 would appear as the value for both dictionary items instead of 0 having 100 and 1 having 120

Comment: You could create a list of the numbers you want to place in the dict. For example ```val = [100,120]``` and then in the for loop you have ```data[i]['stat_3'] = val[i]```

Comment: perfect! just what I needed

Answer (score 1):

```
updated_data = data

updated_data[0].update({'stat_3': 100})

updated_data[1].update({'stat_3': 120})
```

Will sort you, matey.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! So you have to do it twice, you can't do it at once?

Comment: You can, but, IMO itt's premature optimization to try to be clever at this stage of development.

Comment: Then you should have accepted my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner:

```
data = [{'1': 1, '2': 2}, {'11': 11, '22': 22}]
append = {'C': 'c', 'D': 'd', 'E': 'e'}

[d.update(append) for d in data]

print(data)
```

As a side-effect, this creates a `list` full of `None` as long as `len(data)`.  However, no reference to it is saved, so it should be garbage collected immediately.

Output:

```
[{'1': 1, '2': 2, 'C': 'c', 'D': 'd', 'E': 'e'},
{'11': 11, '22': 22, 'C': 'c', 'D': 'd', 'E': 'e'}]
```